# RoboVM don't see my signing identity

Tags: libgdx, robovm

I am trying to export my libgdx game to .ipa. First I got such error:

```
No signing identity found matching 'iPhone Distribution: Alon Zilberman (Y59452PXMM)'
```

Than I checked that I really have identity this way:

```
security find-identity -v -p codesigning
```

And I got list of all my identities:

```
.........
4) C6EE6E2D320E08328E6BBBFB9232862728680199 "iPhone Developer: Alon Zilberman (C45JLF8WFU)"
5) 6C8A911B4344F777C606E5FDACDF4F102F140731 "iPhone Distribution: Alon Zilberman (Y59452PXMM)"
```

Than I downloaded robovm buid and tried this:

```
java -cp lib/robovm-compiler.jar org.robovm.compiler.target.ios.SigningIdentity
```

But I got epmty list:

```
[]
```

I checked the code of `SigningIdentity` and I see that it call the same command I called manually, so I have no idea why it gets empty list. Maybe it is something with permissions?  Will be very thankful for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this bug: https://github.com/robovm/robovm/issues/369  and just remove revoked certificate. It solved the problem.